# Couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell

```
Area (x0:x1:xs) = determinant x0 x1 + Area(x1:xs) + determinant x0 xs
```

I keep getting an error for can't match expected type for the last part which is `determinant x0 xs` namely the `xs` part

Comment: `x0` and `x1` have type `a` for a `[a]` while `xs` has type `[a]` as it is the tail. What are you expecting to pass into `Area`?

Comment: `area` should be lower case. And you haven't shown the definition of `determinant` you're using, or what type you expect your function to have.

Answer (score 1):

```
 determinant :: a-> a -> ...
 determinant x0 x1 

 determinant :: a-> [a] -> ...
 determinant x0 **xs**
```

What type is determinant supposed to have? In the first call it takes x0 x1 that have both type a. In the second call you pass to determinant x0 xs where xs is a list of a ([a]).